# Is there a simple way of applying blur to shapes in syncfusion_flutter_maps?

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, fluttermap

So I am using syncfusion_flutter_maps for a simple map app and I want certain areas on the map to be darkened and blurred out. I figured quite quickly how to do the darkening part with something as simple as this:

```
              sublayers: [
                MapCircleLayer(
                  circles: {
                    MapCircle(
                      center: MapLatLng(
                          _userLocation.latitude, _userLocation.longitude),
                      radius: 50,
                    ),
                  },
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                  strokeColor: Colors.red,
                  strokeWidth: 0,
                ),
              ],
```

but how do I add blur to it?

Trying to add something like BackDropFilter doesnt seem very practical to me vut I couldnt find much about this, despite how well documented this package is.

Alternatively I would be willing to settle for overlaying it with custom image instead.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I am very much aware, its not app for commercial use. I would go for alternative like flutter_map, but using SyncFusion map seems far easier, Tho, I am still at stage of this app where I am willing to rewrite it using some other package if i can find good solution for this

Comment: The problem isn't commercial or not, it's once you get five people "on the team".  If it stays a small personal project, you'll probably not hit that five person total.  But you probably shouldn't publish it open source because the license will need to be valid for the downstream as well.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement can be achieved by using the [MapCircleLayer.inverted](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_maps/latest/maps/MapCircleLayer/MapCircleLayer.inverted.html) property, and its used to highlight a specific area on a map to make it more readable by using the circles property of MapCircleLayer.inverted by adding mask to the outer region of the highlighted circles.

Check [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/maps/vector-layers/polygon-layer#inverted-polygon) to know more about the inverted polygon.